# I can not do "npm install" to my project in React. When I running "npm install" i get error massage

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

When I running "npm install" I get this Error message:

```
found 15369 vulnerabilities (15366 low, 3 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried to run "npm audit" and I get this error message:

```
found 15369 vulnerabilities (15366 low, 3 high) in 2153 scanned packages
  run `npm audit fix` to fix 15366 of them.
  3 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

I tried to run "npm audit fix --force"
and I get this error message:

```
fixed 15366 of 15369 vulnerabilities in 2153 scanned packages
  3 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

I tried to delete my package-lock.json and delete node_modules folder,
and I Tried npm install again.
and I set this warning massage:

```
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Maybe you will know where the problem is?

Comment: This question has been asked before [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089810/npm-install-gives-warnings-npm-audit-fix-not-working)

Comment: I read this post but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. It's a warning message. Should not affect your project to run most of the cases.

Comment: Error message comes in red color in command line. Is it red in your case?aren't you able to run the project with 'npm start'?

Comment: Yes, my Error message comes in red color in command line, And I did not succeed "npm start".

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
npm update
```

It might solve the issue,
Try referring the official documentation [Auditing package dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities).
Also it won't be a problem to run your project successfully

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some problem with the internet connection or some filtering on the internet data?

Comment: I don't have some problems with the internet connection or some filtering on the internet data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning message. Don't worry.

```
npm start
```

And your your project will start on `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was facing similar problem, this worked for me.

- Remove any kind of lock file `package-lock.json` in the local repo.
- Remove local node_modules folder
- Remove global node_modules folder, this can be found at `%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules`.

Try running `npm i` again

If the solution doesn't work with npm and use yarn and install the packages atleast for now.

Answer (score 0):

Check the packages' dependencies in package.json and package-lock.json. Sometimes this can be from depending on different versions of the same node package. You can try npm update first to try to update as much as possible automatically. If that does not work, find the conflicted versions.