# how to fix uglify-js vulnerability?

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle, node-gyp

## npm audit report

uglify-js  <=2.5.0
Severity: critical
Incorrect Handling of Non-Boolean Comparisons During Minification in uglify-js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-34r7-q49f-h37c
Regular Expression Denial of Service in uglify-js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c9f4-xj24-8jqx
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ometajs/node_modules/uglify-js
ometajs  >=2.1.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of uglify-js
node_modules/ometajs
gyp-expansions  >=0.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of ometajs
node_modules/gyp-expansions

3 critical severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow arsalan. *"To address all issues, run: `npm audit fix`"* - so.. did you tried it yet?

Comment: Yes like 100 times it's still giving me this error

Comment: have you tried to upgrade the `uglify-js` to newer version? i checked they are now at version 3. you should mention action you have taken and its result - even if its fail. other qa [suggested to remove `package-lock.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53089885). hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it started working I was using an old version of node js I updated the node js and now it's working thanks for the help. I searched on google everyone was telling me to update uglify-js package.